# Silverlight for RIA

Tags: silverlight, ria

We currently choosing platform for RIA App. I looks at number of possibilities and so far.
Best UI I've seen so far was done on Silverlight. ASP.NET is more common but it's not as dynamic. So here is my question:

Is Silverlight sufficient platform for RIA App ?

Answer (score 1):

A year ago I started a job where I took over development of a Silverlight RIA app. We have since ported the app over to ASP.NET MVC and we are much happier overall. I wrote a blog post that goes over our reasons for switching [here](http://matt-greer.com/blog/2011/02/from-silverlight-to-asp-net-mvc/)

Silverlight is great technology that is truly capable of some amazing stuff. However, in my humble little opinion, it's not quite the ideal platform for a rich web oriented application. HTML/CSS/JS still rule the day if you ask me.

Comment: Thank you for link - I like your reasoning. we really not building web site - rather backoffice application. It is interesting that you said that SL Dev is slower then ASP.NET MVC - I was under opposite impression  - however I am no expert on that subject.

Answer (score 0):

Netflix uses Silverlight for playing movies instead of Flash probably because of .NET. It has a smaller market share but a lot of the demos seem to be very professional.

Why not javascript and HTML?

Comment: Well, I used devexpress components in Windows UI  ( current version of our app ) and wanted to keep UI and user experiences the same. DevExpress have lots of SL components. But I am not sure if SL is good choice since - most of sites I've seen done in ASP.NET or java. or Php.